# Xalan date extension problem

Tags: xslt, xalan, exslt

i'm trying to use the ubuntu cli version of xalan:

```
Xalan version 1.10.0
Xerces version 2.8.0
```

My problem is how to kick in with date functions. I tryed like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="date">

<xsl:import href="date/date.xsl" />
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
date: <xsl:value-of select="date:date()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It gives me back this message:

```
XSLException Type is: XalanXPathException
Message is: The function number 'http://exslt.org/dates-and-times:date' is not available. (file:///home/user/test.xsl, line x, column y)
```

What files or what do i need to change to make those date functions work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/extensionslib.html

> Xalan-C++ includes beta
>   implementations for functions in four
>   of the EXSLT namespaces (some are
>   calls to extension already in the
>   Xalan namespace).

And from http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/apiDocs/XalanEXSLTDateTimeImpl_8hpp.html, it looks like only [`date:date-time()`](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/date-time/date.date-time.html) have been implemented.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to use a later version of Xalan**.

From the **[Xalan J.2.7.1 documentation](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensionslib.html#exslt)**:

EXSLT extensions

> Xalan-Java supports the EXSLT
>   initiative to provide a set of
>   standard extension functions and
>   elements to XSLT users. Xalan-Java
>   includes implementations for the
>   following EXSLT extension modules:
>
> EXSLT common functions   EXSLT math
>   functions   EXSLT set functions
>
> EXSLT date-and-time functions
>
> EXSLT dynamic functions
>
> EXSLT string functions
>
> The EXSLT func:function and
>   func:result elements (see EXSLT -
>   func:function)

Comment: This is not Xalan-Java! It is Xalan c++ and it's the latest version.

Comment: Then, if Xalan C++ doesn't implement EXSLT dates, you can use the `<xalan:script>` element with JS or the date_time library that comes with the XSelerator and is pure XSLT (no extension functions).

Comment: Indeed, Xselerator26.msi contains Samples\Libraries\datetime_lib.xsl that is pure xsl implementation by Martin "Marrow" Rowlinson. "No limitation on use". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346178/does-anyone-have-a-copy-of-the-xselerator-xsl-ide-from-sourceforge

Comment: @Vadzim, Yes, but as the XSelerator is no longer offered (please, correct me if there is some new development), I don't mention this fact as people won't be able to find the XSelerator and would be frustrated.

Comment: I wrote the comment above with still working download link for those people. )

Comment: @Vadzim, You mean the link to topxml.com -- with all the troyans? I wouldn't recommend such a dangerous link. It would be good if someone could provide hosting for the XSelerator.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation shows that it has built-in beta implementations for that subset, however it does not say you cannot import and use the functions from exslt.org. Why can't you? Does Xalan-c++ not support importing functions?

Note that, I *was* able to get the templates working. Just not the functions.