# Does anyone have a copy of the Xselerator XSL IDE from SourceForge?

Tags: xslt

I have been using a licensed copy of the Marrowsoft Xselerator XSL development tool for many years, and have been very happy with it.
However, after a couple of computer upgrades and a subsequent move to a new laptop, my copy of Xselerator finally tells me that the trail period has expired – even though it was the full version that was installed.
I don’t know how to fix this problem.

I did read (somewhere) that Xselerator had been put on SourceForge, but I cannot find it there.

Does anyone have a copy taken from SourceForge that can be shared ?

Comment: It used to be on sourceforge, but the project appears to have been removed. WayBackMachine has the project pages archived, but unfortunately not the binaries: http://web.archive.org/web/20090216221445/http://sourceforge.net/projects/xselerator

Comment: Oh dear. That's a shame. I hope someone took a copy while it was available, then.

Comment: Been searching for the source code, does anyone have a copy?

Answer (score 3):

There are links to the following download locations from Dave Pawson's [Tools for XSL page](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect1/N795.html#d1337e514):

> Xselerator V2.0.44 Setup ([zip file](http://www.topxml.com/xselerator/setup.zip),) (4.6Mb) - or - Xselerator V2.0.44
>   MSI Setup ([MSI Install](http://www.topxml.com/xselerator/XseleratorMSI.zip)) (1.7Mb)(Especially for those who have XP)
>   (November 2001)

***CAUTION: The links are to topxml.com, [which has been known to host suspicious/malicious software(trojans, scripting exploits, etc.).](http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=topxml.com/)***

Comment: These links now go somewhere else entirely.